# Shift/translation functor in a triangulated category

Tags: category-theory, definition, functors, triangulated-categories, additive-categories

I'm trying to get to grips with triangulated categories at the moment. According to Wikipedia, the [shift/translation functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category#Definition) of a triangulated category $\mathcal{C}$ is an "additive automorphism (or for some authors, an auto-equivalence)" $\Sigma:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$. It gives a link to the Wikipedia page [Equivalence of Categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories), which defines an auto-equivalence on a category $\mathcal{C}$ to be a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ for which there exists a functor $G:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ such that $G\circ F$ and $F\circ G$ are 'naturally isomorphic' to the identity functor on $\mathcal{C}$.

In $\S 1.3$ of [*Triangulated Categories*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/triangulated-categories/307C3D943D4CE7F52BAAF7E2BE67F6CC) (Holm & Jørgensen, 2010), the shift/translation functor on $\mathcal{C}$ is described as "an additive functor which is an automorphism (i.e. it is invertible, thus there exists a functor $\Sigma^{-1}$ such that $\Sigma\circ\Sigma^{-1}$ and $\Sigma^{-1}\circ\Sigma$ are the identity functors)".

Unless I've missed something, one is far stricter than the other. In the latter case, $\Sigma$ must be invertible, and behave much like an isomorphism normally does. In the former case, there is a lot more flexibility, and being 'naturally isomorphic' to the identity functor will do.

Many other sources simply refer to an 'auto-equivalence' without stating which of these they refer to. I am fairly new to category theory so please forgive my naivety.

Comment: You are right, there is a big difference between strict and natural isomorphisms.  For instance, in Neeman's book he assumes that $\Sigma$ is a strict equivalence.  However, in many of his early proofs he only needs that $\Sigma$ has both a left and a right adjoint, which would still be true if $\Sigma$ was only a natural equivalence.  Thus, it may not practically matter.  I've been out of the business for a while now, so I don't know what the common modern convention is now.

Comment: The triangulated categories $\mathbf{K} (\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathbf{D} (\mathcal{A})$ coming from categories of chain complexes have shifts that are strictly invertible, so it is not completely unreasonable to demand strictly invertible shifts.
At any rate, I think every triangulated category is equivalent to one with strictly invertible shifts.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you know if there is a consensus either way on how to define it? At this point, I'm just trying to find the most feasible way to make sense of the TC axioms and understand some important examples like the stable homotopy category

Comment: I'm not familiar with triangulated categories and even less familiar with stable homotopy theory, so I can't tell you what the consensus is. I think there are models of the stable homotopy category where you get a strictly invertible shift functor. If the situation is anything like how it is for monoidal categories, I think you will find that the official definitions say that the shift doesn't have to be strictly invertible but in practice people pretend as if it is.